# changing the spacing between list dots?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to change the spacing between sublist dots.
I have two lists coded like this

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

the spaces between the dots of a list and its sublist is huge, similiar to this:

```
*
     *
```

but I want the dots to be close, like this

```
*
  *
```

I tried changing the indent spacing, but that has no effect. Was wondering what the proper code was to do this.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Reduce left margin/padding on `ul ul {}`.

Comment: Use the **margin-left**

Answer (score 2):

To control the spacing vertically between `li` elements, adjust their top and bottom margin in the CSS.

```
/* Example */
li { margin: 10px 0; }
```

To control the spacing on nested sublists, adjust the nested `ul` element's left padding, which is usually given by browsers a default of 40px.

```
/* Example */
ul ul { padding-left: 20px; } /* Cut normal width in half */
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c96x/)

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to sublist

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
    <ul id="test">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

And in the css

```
#test {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Edit: Obviously you have to adjust the pixels of "left", something like 5-10 should do what you want

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add markup to achieve this, since you can select `ul ul`. You also don't need to add relative positioning when you can simply adjust the already existing margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `margin-left` in css
for example

```
 #ul{
    margin-left: -20px;
}

 <ul>
      <li>a</li>

        <ul id="ul">
          <li>b</li>
        </ul>

</ul>
```